# How to give toast message in objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uialertview, toast

I am trying to give a toast message when users login and user will able to see a toast message saying New Data Available and the button beneath that says Download  and Cancel.But when Download comes its font Coming in BOLD.PLease let me know how can i make this look in normal by default fonts

Code as follows:

```
 UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:msg message:@""delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Download" otherButtonTitles: @"Ignore",nil];
```

I need the Download should Come in normal fonts in toast message.

Comment: UIAlertView is not toast, its alert... ;) [use this beautiful lib to show alert](https://github.com/Darktt/DTAlertView)

Comment: `UIAlertView is deprecated : first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead`, and implement like what @NAVEEN KUMAR answered. Do the implementation with latest code. Otherwise later it will be a problem.

Answer (score 10):

I have a Simple code to giving Toast.

```
- (void) ShowAlert:(NSString *)Message {
    UIAlertController * alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                  message:@""
                                                           preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIView *firstSubview = alert.view.subviews.firstObject;
    UIView *alertContentView = firstSubview.subviews.firstObject;
    for (UIView *subSubView in alertContentView.subviews) { 
        subSubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:141/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:254/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    }
    NSMutableAttributedString *AS = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:Message];
    [AS addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor whiteColor] range: NSMakeRange(0,AS.length)];
    [alert setValue:AS forKey:@"attributedTitle"];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        }];
    });
}
```

Use

```
[self ShowAlert:@"Please Enter Your Good Name."];
```

Answer (score 0):

**check it**

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController
                                                        alertControllerWithTitle:@"your text"
                                                        message:nil
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
                            [self performSelector:@selector(abc:) withObject:alert afterDelay:2];

                            UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                                                 actionWithTitle:@"Download"
                                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                                 {
                                                 }];

     UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                                                 actionWithTitle:@"cancel"
                                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                                 {
                                                 }];
                            [alert addAction:ok];
                           [alert addAction:cancel];
                            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil]

        ;
```

**delegate method for automatic disappear**

```
  -(void)abc:(UIAlertController*)x{
            [x dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```

Comment: if u want it u can place ok action otherwise leave it.... or with in 2 sec it will disappear message.

Comment: I want to achieve same functionality using UIAlertView not using UIAlertController

Comment: but u r asking .. giving toast message like android .... its possible ... if u r using UIAlertController.... for me its working ... fine. @user57304

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you need to create one custom Alert View which match your expectations.

For you reference you can choose custom alerts which allow features which you want. (see example links below)

1) Example_1: https://github.com/cs-joao-souza/JPAlertController

2) Example_2: https://github.com/kubacizek/ScrollableDisclaimerAlert

3) Example_3: https://github.com/gokulgovind/GLInAppPurchase

Hope it helps.